# add cronjob to crontab without deleting existing cronjobs

Tags: linux, bash

I have some cronjob scheduled already.

When I do `crontab -e` I will find the existing cronjobs.

```
* * * * *  #Runs every minute
30 * * * *  #Runs at 30 minutes past the hour
45 6 * * *  #Runs at 6:45 am every day
45 18 * * *  #Runs at 6:45 pm every day
00 1 * * 0  #Runs at 1:00 am every Sunday
00 1 * * 7  #Runs at 1:00 am every Sunday
```

Now I want to add another `cronjob` but without manually doing `crontab -e`. and scheduling the job.

I have the cronjob in a file. I have done like below:

```
crontab /home/$USER/new_cronjob
```

When I do like above all the existing jobs are being deleted and only the `new_cronjob` is being added

```
* * * * *  #Runs every minute
30 * * * *  #Runs at 30 minutes past the hour
45 6 * * *  #Runs at 6:45 am every day
45 18 * * *  #Runs at 6:45 pm every day
00 1 * * 0  #Runs at 1:00 am every Sunday
00 1 * * 7  #Runs at 1:00 am every Sunday
* * * * *  /home/$USER/new_cronjob
```

My result when I do `crontab /home/$USER/new_cronjob`:

```
* * * * *  /home/$USER/new_cronjob
```

What is the correct method to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temporary file with all cron jobs:

```
crontab -l > /tmp/temp_crontab
cat /home/$USER/new_cronjob >> /tmp/temp_crontab
crontab /tmp/temp_crontab
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append to your existing crontab by piping the content of both the old crontab and the file to `crontab -`, like this:

```
{ crontab -l; cat /home/$USER/new_cronjob; } | crontab -
```

The `{ ... }` is to group multiple commands.
We group two commands here so that we can pipe the complete output of both together.

Comment: @New_learner I don't know how you're getting that. But all the punctuation and all the spaces in the example line I gave are important. Are you sure you copy-pasted correctly?

Comment: I tried the command you gave

`{ crontab -l; cat /home/$USER/new_cronjob; } | crontab -`

I am getting the below error

`{: Command not found.
45 5 * * * /home/$USER/new_cronjob.sh
}: Command not found.`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the standard approach demonstrated in [@janos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575775/404556), **to prevent duplicate entries** you'll also want to `grep -v` them out before rewriting the crontab:

```
{
    line="* * * * *  /home/$USER/new_cronjob"
    crontab -l | grep -Fv "$line"
    echo "$line"
} 2>/dev/null | crontab -
```